# Code error about recognition facial from the moment it recognizes my face - Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

```
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

def valida_rosto(url_foto):
    foto = fr.load_image_file(url_foto)
    rostos = fr.face_encodings(foto)
    if len(rostos) > 0:
        return True, rostos
    else:
        return False, rostos


def get_rostos():
    rostos_conhecidos = []
    nomes_conhecidos = []

    arthur = valida_rosto("./foto_arthur.png")
    if arthur[0]:
        rostos_conhecidos.append(arthur[1][0])
        nomes_conhecidos.append("Arthur")
        return rostos_conhecidos, nomes_conhecidos

rostos_conhecidos, nomes_dos_rostos = get_rostos()

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    localizacao_dos_rostos = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    rosto_desconhecidos = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, localizacao_dos_rostos)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), rosto_desconhecido in zip(localizacao_dos_rostos, rosto_desconhecidos):
        resultados = fr.compare_faces(rostos_conhecidos, rosto_desconhecido)
        print(resultados)

        face_distances = fr.face_distance(rostos_conhecidos, rosto_desconhecido)

        melhor_id = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if resultados[melhor_id]:
            nome = nomes_dos_rostos[melhor_id]
        else:
            nome = "Desconhecido"

        # Ao redor do rosto
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Embaixo
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        # Texto
        cv2.putText(frame, nome, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        cv2.imshow('Webcam_facerecognition', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code above gives me the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\eduar\trabalho\Reconhfacial\reconhimento_rosto\webcam.py", line 15, in 
rosto_desconhecidos = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, localizacao_dos_rostos)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in 
return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x000001A6F14A7E70>, array([[[146, 144, 131],
[144, 142, 129],
[145, 143, 130],
...,
[183, 177, 163],
[181, 175, 161],
[178, 172, 158]],

```
   [[146, 144, 131],
    [145, 143, 130],
    [145, 143, 130],
    ...,
    [181, 175, 161],
    [178, 172, 158],
    [176, 170, 156]],

   [[147, 145, 132],
    [145, 143, 130],
    [145, 143, 130],
    ...,
    [181, 175, 161],
    [179, 173, 159],
    [177, 171, 157]],

   ...,

   [[ 18,  32,  32],
    [ 15,  29,  29],
    [ 13,  27,  27],
    ...,
    [145, 141, 138],
    [140, 136, 133],
    [142, 138, 135]],

   [[ 18,  30,  30],
    [ 18,  30,  30],
    [ 18,  30,  30],
    ...,
    [144, 140, 137],
    [140, 136, 133],
    [140, 136, 133]],

   [[ 13,  25,  25],
    [ 17,  29,  29],
    [ 21,  33,  33],
    ...,
    [140, 136, 133],
    [136, 132, 129],
    [137, 133, 130]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x000001A6F14B6FB0>, 1
```

The only thing i know is that the error occurs when the webcam identifies my face, furthermore this is my first question so i would like to know what can be wrong or if i could be more explanatory. thanks

In my attempts to make it run, i tried ChatGPT, Youtube videos and some friends but unsuccessfully nothing worked.